# How to center an image inside a google map polygon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polygons

I'm struggling with google map API (with Ionic 3) : 
I create a regular polygon with 6 points on the google map, and I want to put an image on the center.
I have the coordinates of the center and of course, of each point of the polygon.

When I put a marker on the center with an Icon, the bottom-left of the image start on the coordinates I set in the marker.

Does someone know how I can center the image ?